# Getting Specific Array Element - Meteor Mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have this structure

```
{
"_id" : "EbtLm2Nmb79WWryEr",
"notificationByUsers" : {
    "all" : [ 
        {
            "account_id" : "X5PjY66JAwgoxDb4L",
            "date" : ISODate("2016-07-27T13:48:17.154Z"),
            "value" : null
        }, 
        {
            "account_id" : "2C2FKXaKtmeRMNT3E",
            "date" : ISODate("2016-07-27T13:53:10.296Z"),
            "value" : "Instant"
        }, 
        {
            "account_id" : "6Np35oj63cavF4RHs",
            "date" : ISODate("2016-07-28T07:18:22.696Z"),
            "value" : "Instant"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

and i am querying

```
db.Collection.findOne({_id: EbtLm2Nmb79WWryEr, 'notificationByUsers.all':{$elemMatch:{account_id: "2C2FKXaKtmeRMNT3E"}}}, {_id:0, 'notificationByUsers.all.$': 1})
```

it returns in roboMongo

```
{
 "notificationByUsers" : {
"all" : [ 
    {
        "account_id" : "2C2FKXaKtmeRMNT3E",
        "date" : ISODate("2016-07-27T13:53:10.296Z"),
        "value" : "Instant"
    }
]
}
```

But in Meteor it returns all array elements with this query. I want the result with specific array element as working in robomongo.

Comment: Querying client or server side with Meteor?

Comment: Server Side Brother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using fields projection, like:

```
MyCollection.findOne({},{ fields : {_id:0, 'notificationByUsers.all':1}});
```

This will return object like :

```
{
 "notificationByUsers" : {
"all" : [ 
    {
        "account_id" : "2C2FKXaKtmeRMNT3E",
        "date" : ISODate("2016-07-27T13:53:10.296Z"),
        "value" : "Instant"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: `"$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue >1 field in obj: { _id: 0.0, notificationByUsers.all.$: 1.0 }"`
in mongodb

Comment: This is the meteor way my friend.